# Question on differential maps, reading comprehension issue

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

## Problem statement

Do Carmo's differential geometry book has a question that reads:

Define a regular curve in analogy with a regular surface. Prove that

a) (question statement goes here)

b) The inverse image of a regular value of a differentiable map: $$F: U \subset R^3 \rightarrow R^2$$ is a regular curve in $R^3$. Show the relationship between this proposition and the classical way of defining a regular curve as the intersection of two surfaces.

## Confusion

If I read that as is, I am reading 2 clauses the first of which is:

"Prove that: ... The inverse image is a regular curve in $R^3$".

There is no way that that is true in general. for example consider the map $g(x,y,z) = (x + 0y + z, 0x + y + z)$ defined on $R^3 - \{(0,0,0)\}$. The inverse image is most definitely not a curve, but that obeys 100% of all the requirements in the question.

Was the problem trying to ask:

"Prove that, assuming that the pre-image of $F$ is a regular curve, the map is equivalent to the definition of regular curves as the intersection of 2 surfaces."

I.e. Should I take that first sentence as an assumption and not as something I am supposed to prove?

Comment: Your example is not a counterexample. For the regular value $(1,2)$, the preimage is paramterized by $t \mapsto (1,2,t)$, for instance and is a regular curve. (Of course it works for any $(x,y)$ other than the origin, not just $(1,2)$.

Comment: That's not a regular curve actually, the derivative vanishes.

Comment: But I also seem to be wrong about my assumptions. Maybe I don;t understand the problem compeltely.

Comment: ohhhh I understand why it must be a curve now.

There are 2 implicit functions for the coordinates. each one takes the dimension down by one, And then a point must satisfy both at the same time, which removes an additional dimension!

Comment: The derivative does not vanish, in fact it is $(1,2,1)$.

Comment: @treble the first derivative with respect to t (0,0,1) the second derivative is (0,0,0)